# Onclick event to add and remove element

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I'm trying to create a onclick event that can add and remove an element multiple times. I've considered using `setproperty` and changing `visibility`(as well as `:after` pseudo-class), but it will require changing the `position` which breaks a lot of things in the document. So far I've only been able to come up with ways that add the element once, then deletes it once. Is there a way to make this happen more than once(every time you click the element)?

```js
// Create New Element
let html = document.createElement('p');
html.className = 'skills';
html.id = 'html-skills';
html.setAttribute('title', 'HTML5 Proficiency');
html.appendChild(document.createTextNode('5%'));
html.style.setProperty('font-size', '16px')
// Grab Old Element
const oldHTML = document.getElementById('html');
// On Click function to add element
oldHTML.addEventListener('click', onClick);
function onClick(e) {
    document.getElementById('htmlJS').appendChild(html)
}
// On click function to remove element
const htmlJS = document.getElementById('htmlJS')
html.addEventListener('click', removeHTML);
function removeHTML(e) {
    let newHTML = document.getElementById("htmlJS");
    let htmlNested = document.getElementById("htmlJS").lastChild;
   
    htmlNested.lastChild.remove();
}
```

```html
 <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d3d2bbf2ae.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
 ></script>
 
 <div class="skills-list__1 skills-icons" id="skills1">
  <i class="fab fa-html5 html" id="html" title="HTML5"><div id="htmlJS"></div></i>
 </div>
```

Comment: The question isn't very clear, can you please post a code snippet which we can execute and see using the <> in the editor ?

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea that was available. Basically there's an icon element in html that once clicked loads paragraph element. When you click the paragraph element it then removes it. I'm trying to figure out how to do that multiple times. Right now it simply disappears for good and doesn't run again.

Comment: Just one more thing, are you looking to hide and show this element(5%) on click? because you are using htmlNested.lastChild.remove(); which removes this element from the DOM itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't reuse onClick function(making '5%' html) is that you have overwritten the function with removeHTML function. I used one event function to write and delete inner html text. There are many ways to what do you want. Hope you try you own way.

```js
// Create New Element
let html = document.createElement('p');
html.className = 'skills';
html.id = 'html-skills';
html.setAttribute('title', 'HTML5 Proficiency');
html.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
html.style.setProperty('font-size', '16px')
document.getElementById('htmlJS').appendChild(html)
// Grab Old Element
const oldHTML = document.getElementById('html');
// On Click function to add element
oldHTML.addEventListener('click', onClick);
function onClick(e) {
if (html.innerHTML === '') {
  html.innerHTML = '5%'
  } else {
  html.innerHTML = ''
  }
}
// On click function to remove element
//Whatever you named this htmlJS id it still has onCLick function.
const htmlJS = document.getElementById('htmlJS')
html.addEventListener('click', removeHTML);
function removeHTML(e) {
    let newHTML = document.getElementById("htmlJS");
    let htmlNested = document.getElementById("htmlJS").lastChild;   
}
```

```html
 <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d3d2bbf2ae.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
 ></script>
 
 <div class="skills-list__1 skills-icons" id="skills1">
  <i class="fab fa-html5 html" id="html" title="HTML5"><div id="htmlJS"></div></i>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm hitting myself in the head over this answer right now. I initially thought about using an if statement like that, but because I tried adding empty quotes with CSS and the display property thinking it would cascade and override(style.setpropery display: hidden ---> display: '')I disregarded that because I thought it wasn't a thing with any of the languages.